# C# serial port DATA read hang problem

Tags: c#

I want to continuosly read DATA on serial port

DATA format is A5 30 31 32 32....... 0D

almost 50bytes recieved on one query

I do it with 
DATA = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
line code but program will hang after two three queries.

Kindly anyone share a simple serial port code.

Ashraf

Comment: show us more code, such as your loop and the setup of the serial line

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a defective serial port.  Try connecting your device to a different port.

Comment: My device is actually do not response some time on query

Answer (score 0):

Your call to ReadByte() may simply be stuck in an infinite timeout waiting for more data that doesn't come through.

Are you sure you continue to receive data? Are you sure you setup the baudrate, parity, stopbits and handshake correctly?

Comment: serialPort1.PortName = ("COM1");
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
           
            serialPort1.Open();
            while (_Continue)
            {

                DATA = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
                    


                if (DATA == 13)
                {
                    byte_count = 0;
                    packet_started = false;
                    _Continue = false;

                }
                

            }
                serialPort1.Close();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
[SerialPort.ReadExisting Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting.aspx)

Reads all immediately available bytes, based on the encoding, in both the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.

Here is a sample code i used, it works fine to me

```
 public static string ReadMessage(int index)
    {
        using (SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(_portNumber))
        {
            sp.Open();
            sp.Write("AT+CMGR=" + index + "\r");

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            return sp.ReadExisting();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Here is the complete class i used.
http://goo.gl/9Y3SZ
My application was to access message using serial port from a GSM Modem. Hope this helps.