# SerialDataReceivedEventHandler;

Tags: c#

```
while (true)
{
 serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port1_DataReceived);
 }
private void port1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  Thread.Sleep(1);
  byte DATA = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
  Console.WriteLine(DATA);
  //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(DATA));
}
```

I can see serial DATA on console but I do not know how to handle this DATA and show it on textBox etc.
what is missing in my code

Comment: Anybody mystified about that while loop?  Check out the OP's previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200397/c-serial-port-data-read-hang-problem

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @adatapost answer:

Fist:

```
 while(true)
 {
   serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port1_DataReceived);
 } ???!!
```

Hope this is just wrong copy/paste, cause subscribe to the event in infinite `while` loop !

Second: it's not clear what you want to *see* on the screen.

If just symbols the first answer is pretty suitable, if not you shoud read your device documentation (printer, bill counter, RFID reader.. whatever) to know how to *treat*  those bytes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This loop start with the button click and i also send a query to device in this while loop and that device reply me correctly , i have checked it on console. i just take that DATA and display it on TextBox.

Comment: @Muhamad Ashraf: your byte data are just numbers/symbols, so what you want the user see on screen ?

Comment: user want to see those DATA bytes on textBoxes. actually device send around 50bytes on a single query.

Comment: If you want just byte by byte visualization consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8.aspx Ascii.GetString method.

Comment: problem is not the byte DATA , problem is to the thread handling

Comment: and display even a single byte on a textBox. SerialDataReceivedEventHandler do not allow to use textBox within the event

Comment: Cause you don't change text box from UI thread. Have look here to see how you can do that within event handler too. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx

Comment: thanks Tigran, i have used timer for DATA update and delete the while loop from my Program. It is now working

Comment: @Muhamad consider to ACCEPT the answer you think is corrector helped you, if you want suceed on this site. You have to vahe a Check under every answer you have on, in order to ACCEPT the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToBase64String()` method. This method convert byte array into Base64 string.

EDIT:

@Muhammad Ashraf : problem is not the byte DATA , problem is to the thread handling.

Yes It is cross-thread issue. You may use Invoke method.

```
private void port1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  Thread.Sleep(1);
  byte DATA = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
  String data=Convert.ToString(DATA);

  if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
   {
     textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { textBox1.Text = data; }));
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually DATA is there in byte DATA. I can use byte array but i dont know how byte DATA will return to main program.

Comment: any body there who can tell me how to read DATA from SerialDataReceivedEventHandler;

Comment: when i pass the DATA into textBox within serialeventhandler it says thread problem